# Accessing JavaScript in-memory objects

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-harmony

Is it possible to access JS in-memory objects from within the code? Are there any internal memory inspectors available? Can I list the objects with a given prototype (or type) from code?

```
// EXAMPLE
function Kitten(name) { this.name = name; }
var kitten = new Kitten('furry');
// ...
// Any features like this?
var kittens = ListObjectsOfType(Kitten);
// Or this?
var kittens2 = ListObjectsWithPrototype(kitten.prototype);
```

Primarily I'm interested in Google's V8 implementations or ES6 (Harmony) specifications. (I appreciate other technologies too.)

Comment: Which implementation of JavaScript? There is no standard way to do this anyway

Comment: I'm focusing on V8 (Chrome, Node). I'm interested in the currently available technologies and if there is any ES6 standard to be implemented later

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for this. Something like:

```
function ListObjectsOfType(type) {
    var result = [];
    for( var w in window ) {
        var val = window[w];
        if( val instanceof type )
            result.push(val);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you invoke this from the Chrome Console, you can plainly inspect/collapse the resulting objects.
You can extend it to traverse all window vars (you'll want to skip the defaults though).
I think by definition it is impossible to inspect e.g. the following:

```
function SomeObj() {
    var b = new Kitten('kitty');
}
new SomeObj();
```

I expect the memory heap to have this obj, but it will not be available/detectable via JS ever.

Comment: Yeah, this lists the properties of the `window` (i.e. the global variables), but it's far from being a memory inspector. The local variables (`function() { var k = new Kitten('meow')}`) and member variables are not listed here.

Comment: Agreed. The Chrome Devtools have a feature to see the memory and its objects, but you cannot runtime inspect it with a function, as far as I know. This example can be extended by inspecting every object that is one way or another referenced, but some objects are I think by definition not accessible since they live in a local scope.